# Position title on border-bottom

Tags: html, css

Im trying to create a Polaroid looking photo frame that's responsive. 
The problem is that the title wont stick to the bottom-border, it just float over the image.

If im using pixels instead of percent it works, but not other wise. 
Any ideas ?

[**the fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/NWWQ3/)

HTML

```
<div class="imageContainer">
  <img src="http://photogallery.indiatimes.com/beauty-pageants/miss-india/rochelle-maria-raos-photo-shoot/photo/16651703/Miss-India-International-Rochelle-Maria-Rao-during-her-photo-shoot-.jpg" />
    <p> Title</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.imageContainer {
    position: relative;
    width: 25%;
    padding-bottom: 25%;
    float: left;
    height: 0;
    margin-right:10px;
    border:10px solid #e3e3e3;
    border-bottom:30px solid #e3e3e3;
}

.imageContainer img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
}
.imageContainer p{
    position:absolute;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing is incorrect, you are using thick borders around the image which is preventing the inner text to flow over it, in order to achieve that you need to use negative `bottom` value for your `title`

```
.imageContainer p{
    position:absolute;
    bottom: -40px;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/NWWQ3/1/)

Instead of this approach I would suggest you to use `display: inline-block;` `li` elements with nested `div` & `img` tag, `div` with a fixed height and `img` with fixed `min` `height` and `width` with your title element positioned `absolute` at `bottom 0`

Comment: Great! +1 for the suggestion will def try it right now.
Thanks.

Comment: @Dymond that's cleaner :) happy coding

Answer (score 1):

Add this to the `.imageContainer p` declaration:

```
bottom: -40px;
```